# Internal Server Error in Jmeter Script

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create Jmeter scripts for our PEGA application, but every time reply scripts fail due to the following issue.

Can anyone help?

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-08-12 08:38:58 IST
Load time: 604
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 603
Size in bytes: 4267
Headers size in bytes: 1774
Body size in bytes: 2493
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: Pega-RULES=H79D7E64B2C531F36AE825FC87DA355F5; Version=1; Comment="PegaRULES session tracking"; Path=/prweb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably are missing either a header or a cookie.

I suggest you try to record traffic using JMeter Test Script Recorder so that you avoid any missing header.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

This way you won't miss any header or cookie.

Then see what need to be variabilized using Post Processor and variables (${varName})